# ReactJS: How can I update cloned child props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `IconsGrid` component with children of type `Icon`, here is an example:

```
<IconsGrid iconsWidth={96} iconsHeight={96}>
    <Icon iconClass="fa fa-cog" onIconClick={...} />
    <Icon iconClass="fa fa-settings onIconClick={...} />
    <Icon iconClass="fa fa-twitter" onIconClick={...} />
</IconsGrid>
```

The `IconGrid` is 100% width and 100% height of the sceen, inside it's render method, I'm cloning all the `Icon` children with `React.cloneElement` because i need to pass more props to each icon like `top` and `left` to position the icons on the grid.

Each of `Icon` child is draggable, meaning that while dragging, I need to update its own `top` and `left` properties, the proplem is that the `top` and `left` props are both comming from the cloned `Icon` in the `IconsGrid` component.
So how can I update a cloned child props from it's parent component?

What I tried is to pass a function to the cloned icon as a prop and while dragging the icon, on the mouse move event, i'm calling this function with the icon component and it's new top and left positions, but then I cant call `icon.setProps` or `icon.replaceProps`

Comment: You could update the IconsGrid component to accept an array of icon strings as well as the Icon component class and then create them inside of IconsGrid

Comment: Are you passing the additional props as state? Perhaps that would work.

Comment: @CoryDanielson this is part of a ui framework im building, i want it to be transparent for the developer

Comment: I'm not really sure why you would need to update the top & left as props while dragging. It seems like something you should only need to do after the dragging is completed

Comment: @CoryDanielson you are absolutely right but when i drop the icon i still need to update the top and left props, the reason is that i don't want the top and left props of each icon to be reset when the IconsGrid state is changed